# How to install the py2exe modul in Linux

Tags: python, installation, py2exe

I downloaded the actual py2exe package.
But I've no idea how to get it in my system. I mean I can follow the tutorial a 100% but I can't find anything how to install py2exe to my kubuntu 11.10.
I also can't find a py2exe.py which I could include to my workingfolder.

Could some please help me the project has to be finish till tomorrow?

Thanks for your help

cheers,
Chris

Comment: For linux, have a look at freeze http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

Comment: Or cxFreeze, works fine on Linux.

Comment: @Fredrik In linux, why not just make the script executable with chmod?

Comment: @user850498 - sometimes you don't want to ship the code. py2exe allows someone to run a python program on a machine where python isn't installed.

Answer (score 10):

Py2exe has to run on Windows, you can not run it in Linux. (Maybe wine can help, but I'm not sure)

Comment: well ok that explains a lot :) thank you!
and i can tell wine isnt able to execute it (on my computer)

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to generate a certificate file to use py2exe. Try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead.